# How can I unionize and find the median time in this raw SQL call?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, union

I am trying to

1. collect two different `type`'s objects (`Published` and `InReviewing` from the same model `Events`,
2. find the medium time between the `Published` and `Created`,
3. group those by date..

So that I can return an array with a date, and a medium time difference between any of the types `InReviewing` and `Published` that share a `target_id` from each day. I think SQL would return seconds?

Example :

```
[[Mon, 03 Dec 2012, 110000], [Thu, 13 Dec 2012, 2200000]]
```

My raw SQL syntax is lacking some conclusions. This is what I have so far :

```
    SELECT target_id, DATE(created_at), COUNT(*)
    FROM (   SELECT target_id, DATE(created_at)
          FROM events
          WHERE created_at > '#{@start_time}'
          AND events.type = 'InReviewing'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT target_id, DATE(created_at)
          FROM events
          WHERE created_at > '#{@start_time}'
          AND events.type = 'Published'   
      ) tmp
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Don't mind the `#{@start_time`}`, that's using native code to implement a Time here, and it works properly..

Thanks!

Comment: difference =  unix_timestamp(theone) - unix_timestamp(theother)

Comment: I'm embarrassingly not familiar enough to implement that suggestion.. This helps though, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question but I still decided to give it a shot (also, since I don't have access to MySql at this time, this example is from MS SQL):

```
    SELECT x.target_id, x.created_at AS InReviewingCreated, y.created_at AS PublishedCreated, DATEDIFF(SECOND, x.created_at, y.created_at) AS DiffSeconds 
FROM 
    (SELECT *
        FROM Events a 
        WHERE a.created_at > '#{@start_time}'
            AND a.type = 'InReviewing') x INNER JOIN

    (SELECT *
        FROM Events a 
        WHERE a.created_at > '#{@start_time}'
            AND a.type = 'Published') y ON x.target_id = y.target_id
ORDER BY x.created_at
```

This will give you the timestamps for when each of the target was InReview and Published and the number of seconds between them. I am a little confused about what you want ...
here is what I "think" you want:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, x.created_at), AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, x.created_at, y.created_at))
FROM 
    (SELECT *
        FROM Events a 
        WHERE a.created_at > '#{@start_time}'
            AND a.type = 'InReviewing') x INNER JOIN

    (SELECT *
        FROM Events a 
        WHERE a.created_at > '#{@start_time}'
            AND a.type = 'Published') y ON x.target_id = y.target_id
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, x.created_at)
ORDER BY DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, x.created_at)
```

DISCLAIMER: Since I don't have your table schema, my test isn't exactly valid. If you were to share an example setup and required output, then I could provide a better query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not knowing either SQL or MS SQL so well, this is kinda tricky. But I see you instantiate `x` and `y`. Are those implied in MS SQL? Or am I missing some kind of instantiation of those variables somewhere else?

Comment: Ah nice I totally figured it out based on your response! Thanks Nabheet!

Comment: You are welcome. It was a shot in the dark, glad it helped. I think of x and y as aliases for the sub-query. The difference between the queries is how the output is handled. In the first one the output is just a list of target_id, ReviewingCreated and Publishedcreated and an order by. The second one does a little bit of extra work. It computes the average of the time difference, in seconds, for each day of the year.